# Minimizing a function of the form $\sum_{k=2}^N \frac{1}{1-\lambda_k}$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am new to optimization and I would like to know if there are any results/methods for the following optimization problem:

$$\text{Minimize: }T = \sum_{k=2}^N \frac{1}{1-\lambda_k}\text{ subject to: } \sum_{k=2}^N \lambda_k = -1 \text{ and } |\lambda_k| \leq 1$$

It worth mention that $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix.

Can I say something about the distribution of $\lambda_k$ that minimize my objective function?

Does this problem follow any special class of problems? Where should I look for more information on this type of problems?

Comment: Look at the inequality between the harmonic mean and the arithmetic mean. minimizing $T$ is the same as maximizing $(N-1)/T$, which is $\leq (\sum_{k=2}^{N}(1-\lambda_k))/(N-1)=(N-1+1)/(N-1)$. The equality is attained when all $1-\lambda_k$ are the same.

Comment: Therefore, the minimum is $\frac{(N-1)^2}{N}$ and it is attained when all $\lambda_k=-1/(N-1)$.